# Add Something Invisible To HTML Document For Testing

Tags: html, testing

If I just want to add something invisible to an HTML document for testing purposes, what would you suggest? Maybe just an HTML comment that can be searched for? The purpose is to know what HTML document has been rendered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A comment probably makes most sense.

You could also use a `<input type="hidden">` form element, or  any kind of element with a `display: none`, but that is rather ugly. This sounds like something a comment is suited perfectly for.

Comment: KISS: Keep It Simple Student?  Yes, I agree. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want it less visible, you can use a header (PHP `header()` method). It will not be visible if you simply view source - you will instead need to use software like Firebug to view it.

Comment: nice idea!  In this situation, I have HTML email content which is rendered so it does not apply. However, I like the idea!